# Why am I feeling funky?

Tags: earthbound

When I am in battle, before I attack, it keeps saying I am feeling funky. What does that mean? Does it have any effect on my character?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It appears that you have been "[**Mushroomized**](http://earthbound.wikia.com/wiki/Mushroom)".

> Mushroomization is a status condition caused by mushroom enemies such as the Ramblin' Evil Mushroom. In the overworld, the mushrooms cause the controls to scramble positions while walking around and it also makes a mushroom appear on the head of whoever is inflicted. While in-battle, it may cause a character to attack a party member or heal an enemy. **If the prompt "[character name] is feeling funky!" appears after you select your move, the effects will take place.**

Emphasis mine.

In other words: "Feeling funky" is the EarthBound equivalent to "being confused" in many other RPGs.

Comment: I must learn from you, oh great formatting king.

Comment: @Winter. You can click on the "edit" link to see how a post has been formatted. Also, on the upper right corner of the editor, there's a question mark button; below it (after clicking on it), you have "advanced help".

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it. I like the look and clarity of your answer.

Answer (score 18):

This is a status condition called **Mushroomized** that comes from mushroom type enemies. It's very similar to "confusion" in most other games where it can cause the infected player to unwantedly attack allies.

You should be able to remove the effect by visiting the hospital. IIRC there is a man in the lobby that you can talk to who will remove the effect.

[Here's a quick run down of mushroomized and its effects.](http://earthbound.wikia.com/wiki/Mushroom)

Comment: The man is called the healer, he's mostly bald with little tufts of blue hair.  As a bonus, he'll pay you for the shrooms!

Answer (score 0):

There is a second effect to confusion, your character will eventually run in directions that are not the direction you are pointing. Sometimes, the control is flipped-down is up, left is right. Other times, it is 1/4 turned-up is right, right is down, down is left, left is up. Better to get rid of it as soon as possible!